# Pandas merge produces no data

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

df1:

```
branch    sessions users
toledo    10       3
new york  14       2
boston    102      43
seattle   9        7
```

df2:

```
branch    guests
toledo    10      
new york  14       
boston    102      
seattle   9
```

The result I'm looking for merges the "guests" column from df2 to df1 like this:
df1:

```
branch    sessions users  guests
toledo    10       3      10
new york  14       2      14
boston    102      43     102
seattle   9        7      9
```

I've tried `concat`, `join` and `merge` with no luck.

With `merge`

```
guest_sessions = df2[['branch','guests']].copy()
pd.merge(df1, guest_sessions, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I get this:

```
branch_x    sessions    users   guests_x    branch_y    guests_y
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `Index` for these DataFrames? Since you do `df2[['branch','guests']]` it seems like `branch` is not the Index, so these just have mis-aligned indices. Looks like you just need to do `on='branch'`

Comment: @ALollz That worked, thanks!